# Why is my GET request to API returning 404?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm making a React app that acts as an e-commerce website. I'm trying to use Axios to fetch data from a PostgreSQL API. On Postico, I can see the database with the products I'm trying to fetch.

I'm connected to the database and through the terminal I get the message from postgres:

`You are connected to database "(samedb)" as user "(me)" via socket in "/tmp" at port "5432".`

In the server folder I'm using Sequelize to connect to the database like so:

```
const db = new Sequelize(`postgres://localhost:5432/(samedb)`, config);
```

I'm creating an Express application and mounting my routes on it like this:

```
const app = express();
module.exports = app;

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api", require("./api")):

app.use("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "public/index.html"));
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (path.extname(req.path).length) {
    const err = new Error("Not found");
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message || "Internal server error.");
});
```

Inside the index.js of the api folder I refer to, I have:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
module.exports = router;

//Other routes

router.use("/products", require("./products"))
```

Which refers to the products.js file in the same folder, which states:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const {
  models: { Product },
} = require("../db");
module.exports = router;

//GET @ /api/products
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const products = await Product.findAll({
      attributes: ["id", "name", "price"],
    });
    res.json(products);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

When I go to the page that runs the Axios call (http://localhost:3000/shop), it immediately causes a 404 error and an AxiosError which state the following, respectively:

`GET http://localhost:3000/api/products 404 (Not Found)`

and

`AxiosError code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST" message: "Request failed with status code 404" name: "AxiosError" request: XMLHttpRequest response: {data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta char…e>Cannot GET /api/products stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:82984:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend`

When I use Insomnia to see what's going on at the api route in the error (http://localhost:3000/api/products), it returns the index.html and the 200 status code. Even when I comment out all the app routes that send the response with the index.html, it still sends that file with a 200 status code, while displaying 404 in the browser. I have tried to send Insomnia requests to port 5432 also, but it responds with

`Error: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)`

I think there's something I'm not understanding. I have mounted the /api/ routes on the app, and I expect for the router's GET request in the /api/products file to return the products, but it does not even run. When I add a console.log there, it still only sends back the standard 404 error.

I've made sure that all of the packages I need are installed, and that Sequelize is using the 5432 port and correct db name.

Comment: Are react app and express running on the same port?

Comment: @Konrad They were running on different ports, but I discovered that I was not starting the server, only the React app. By looking more into ports as the issue I discovered this. I'm a learning developer. Thank you for your help!